# Reminder email on Expiry Date field in SharePoint List

Tags: list, flow, reminder

I am seeking a solution whereby SP sends a reminder to a group of emails, once an item in SP List gets expired based on the Expiry Date field. Can someone help with the flow?

Answer (score 0):

Recently Microsoft has released out of the box reminder functionality for each list / library in SharePoint online.... you will see this option where we see flow, powerapps just above the list view in the ribbon area.... you can try this.